# Как переименовать .PDF файлы в извлеченный из файлов текст?

Tags: python, pdf, google-drive

Нужна помощь. Есть большое кол-во .pdf файлов. Некоторыми строками они однообразны по своей структуре и в каждом файле есть строка "ФО ******" * - нумерация документа из 6 цифр. Я хочу с помощью python пройтись по всем .pdf файлам в папке и переименовать их в соответствии этому номеру, чтобы я мог искать их по имени на гугл диске, т.к гугл не индексирует мои файлы и не работает поиск по содержимому. Какая библиотека может мне в этом помочь?

Comment: Пример pdf файла весьма помог бы ответить. Вдруг это jpg обернутый в pdf а не текст?

Comment: Эти pdf -  сканы цветного документа, на котором напечатаны данные. Вообще гугл диск распознает внутри этих pdf текст, но по каким-то причинам у новых загруженных файлах этот поиск не работает. Получится ли с таким .pdf работать и извлечь оттуда строку, переименовав ей файл?

Comment: Изначально я написал скрипт на пайтоне, который ищет на гугл диске файлы по содержанию этой строки, но увы, находит у старых и не находит у новых, решил обойтись переименованием документов. Но их очень много, чтобы делать это вручную.

Comment: Если эти pdf сканы (фотографии), то текст в них вы не найдете.

Comment: Нет, ну почему, найти можно, но это уже машинное обучение))